# Policy Troubleshooter for create permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to troubleshoot a weird "permissions denied" error on Google Cloud (a case where the Service Account is Owner of the project but can't create a default network in the project).

I was turning to Policy Troubleshooter to understand better why the permission was denied. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option for checking create permissions (only get, delete, ...) and I couldn't find any more information in the documentation.

Am I missing something or is this just not a feature of the product?

Comment: Owner role does not have all permissions. Check you may need an **Admin role** for your project to access IAM resources. Project owners and IAM members with the Compute Network Admin role (**roles/compute.networkAdmin**) can create allocated IP address ranges and manage private connections.

Comment: It's important to note that the reason for Permission denied error due to the **Service networking service agent role** is missing in the service project. Refer [SA permissions](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#service_account_permissions). For better understanding about the issue, provide replicating steps to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VeeraNagireddy - the problem is that I am unable to replicate the behaviour on other projects, it's only this project in particular. The error states `compute.networks.create` is missing which an Owner definitely has according to the [Permissions Reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference). Since the case Is so specific, I was hoping to use Policy Troubleshooter to get more insight - do you have experience with that?

Comment: If the access issue still needs further investigation, **Troubleshooter doesn't support break glass access yet, so you can't access Troubleshooter to debug customers' issue**. **Google-admin** If manual investigation is needed, [google-admin](https://google-admin.corp.google.com/) is a good starting point. By examining **Cloud Project > Cloud Project Overview**, you can verify IAM policy and inherited policy. Pay attention to the GAIA disabled/deleted column of each binding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Google internal tooling. We did verify if the serviceAccount in question is an Owner on the project using `gcloud`